# Saving LINQ to oracle database

Tags: c#, oracle

I have following xml file:

```
<os:tax>
 <os:cat name="abc" id="1">
     <os:subcat name="bcd" id="11">
         <os:t name="def" id="111">
             <os:cut name="hello" id="161" cutURL="/abc/a.html"/>
             <os:cut name="hello2" id="162" cutURL="/abc1/a1.html"/>
             <os:cut name="hello3" id="163" cutURL="/abc4/a3.html"/>
         </os:t>
     </os:subcat>
     <os:subcat name="xyz" id="33">
         <os:t name="def" id="333">
             <os:cut name="hello" id="181" cutURL="/abcs/a.html"/>
             <os:cut name="hello2" id="182" cutURL="/abcs5/a1.html"/>
             <os:cut name="hello3" id="183" cutURL="/abcs6/a3.html"/>
         </os:t>
     </os:subcat>
 </os:cat>
 <os:cat name="def" id="2">
     <os:subcat name="bcd" id="22">
         <os:t name="def" id="222">
             <os:cut name="hello" id="171" cutURL="/abcs/a.html"/>
             <os:cut name="hello2" id="172" cutURL="/abcs1/a1.html"/>
             <os:cut name="hello3" id="173" cutURL="/abcs4/a3.html"/>
         </os:t>
     </os:subcat>
 </os:cat>
</os:tax>
```

With the help of someone from stackoverflow i have the working LINQ to get the data out from the file which is this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("tax.xml");
XNamespace os = "http://something"; // You haven't included the declaration...

var query = from cat in doc.Descendants(os + "cat")
        from subcat in cat.Elements(os + "subcat")
        from t in subcat.Elements(os + "t")
        from cut in t.Elements(os + "cut")
        select new
        {
            CatId = (int) cat.Attribute("id"),
            CatName = (string) cat.Attribute("name"),
            SubCatId = (int) subcat.Attribute("id"),
            SubCatName = (string) subcat.Attribute("name"),
            TId = (int) t.Attribute("id"),
            TName = (string) t.Attribute("name"),
            CutId = (int) cut.Attribute("id")
            CutName = (string) cut.Attribute("name")
            CutUrl = (string) cut.Attribute("cutURL")
        };
```

Can someone please tell me how can i save this data to oracle database using this store procedure:

```
abc (id   in varchar2,
     level           in varchar2,
     title           in varchar2,
     parent_id       in varchar2,
     cuturl          in varchar2)
```

id(will save all the ids like cat, subcat, t, cut. then there title parent id is id above the current id.